# My session in next auth doesn't return my own added key value pair

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to pass the sample for my session in nextjs. But if I console log the returning value of it. The sample key-value pair doesn't show. I'm just curious if is it natural that we cannot add anything to it.

```js
providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        // Connect to the database
        await db.connect();
        // Find the user with the given email
        const user = await User.findOne({
          email: credentials.email,
        });
        // Disconnect from the database
        await db.disconnect();
        // Check if the password matches the hashed password in the database
        if (user && bcryptjs.compareSync(credentials.password, user.password)) {
          // Return the user's data if authentication is successful
          return {
            _id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            image: 'f',
            sample: 'someValue',
            isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
          };
        }
        // Throw an error if authentication is unsuccessful
        throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
      },
    }),
 ],
```